# Can we use official icons for commercial use

Tags: legal

Can I use the Ruby on Rails icon for my serviced based company. (Commercial use.)

http://rubyonrails.org/

[image]

Same for Android and iPhone/iPad.

Comment: You should consult an attorney.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any doubts you should get permission from the respective rights holder.

Contact the company, explain what you are wanting to do.

If you are linking back to the Ruby-on-Rails site (for example) I can't see that they'd refuse. As long as you weren't claiming to be something you're not you *should* be OK.

(Subject to the I'm Not A Lawyer clause).

Comment: Also they might not wish to appear to be endorsing your services and could refuse on that ground.